# Creating a wrapper/decorator component in Android?

Tags: android, decorator, android-custom-view, higher-order-components

I have a view that needs to look something like this:

```
<ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/wrapper">
    <ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/wrapped">
        <ViewGroup/>
    </ConstraintLayout>
    <Button/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

But I want to use in my layout like this:

```
<CustomComponent>
    <ViewGroup/>
</CustomComponent>
```

So basically I want to write a CustomComponent to inject the ViewGroup that's its child into the ConstraintLayout with id "wrapped", add a button below it and wrap the whole thing in the "wrapper" ConstraintLayout.

In libraries like React, this could be done using HOCs that composed existing views and added functionalities to it. But here it doesn't seem to be that intuitive to implement.

My approach was something like:

```
class CustomComponent extends ConstraintLayout {
    public void init(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.wrapper, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        View child = getChildAt(1);
        removeView(child);
        ViewGroup wrapped= findViewById(R.id.wrapped);
        wrapped.addView(child);
    }
}
```

So basically the ViewGroup gets added at the end so I have to manually remove it and then add it again to the "wrapped" ConstraintLayout. This seems wasteful and even error prone; Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: use light container like `class CustomComponent extends FrameLayout { ...`

Comment: Ok, but that would just change my root element to FrameLayout. I would still need to remove and add the child view right?

Comment: btw tried to use ViewStub or I missed your point?

Comment: Hadn't heard of a ViewStub but after a bit of reading it doesn't look like what I need. This ViewStub seems to be like an include tag that loads layouts at runtime for better performance. I don't need to do any lazy loading. In fact I have a working layout and everything is fine, just wanted to change the way I write the code in xml ie. have a component wrap an existing layout (maybe add a few elements around it, attach a few listeners etc) without having to worry about inflating my child elements. Hope I haven't misunderstood the point of a ViewStub, will have one more look into it.

Comment: OK so maybe LayoutInflater.Factory[2] is what you need? you use it by calling setFactory on active LayoutInflater object

Comment: Hadn't heard of that either, but reading through a bit, this looks like a way to override the inflation process. If so, this might be what I need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158799/discussion-between-indgov-and-pskink).